# PHPStorm - Invalid descendent file name

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, sftp, phpstorm

I'm attempting to sync my local PHPStorm project from my Windows 7 PC with my Ubuntu server.

When I try any kind of connection (e.g. "Test SFTP connection"), it fails with

`Invalid descendent file name "C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt"`

the folder mentioned doesn't exist on my Windows machine, and of course not on my Ubuntu server.

Even the most basic operation connecting to the Ubuntu server is failing because of this - Jetbrains support suggested asking here, so does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have a file on your Ubuntu server with that `C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt` name. YES -- it's on Ubuntu and YES -- it's actually a file name and not full path (Linux allows `:` and `\` characters in file names).

Unfortunately such file name is invalid on Windows and library used for SFTP communications in PhpStorm does not allow to process such files in any way (yes, it's valid as **full path** but not as **file name alone**).

The solution is to connect to your SFTP using another program (e.g. FileZilla) and delete that file. After that you will be able to continue with PhpStorm built-in SFTP functionality.

P.S.
Such file is usually created by Firefox on Linux (google that file name for additional details).

https://askubuntu.com/questions/144408/what-is-the-file-c-nppdf32log-debuglog-txt

---

> Jetbrains support suggested asking here

That's odd (and hard to believe for me) -- they should know about such issue for sure -- you are not first who is facing the same error.

In any case -- this is the ticket to watch after -- hopefully the used library (for SFTP communications) will allow handling such situations better in the future.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2449

Comment: Weird - that was the problem. Further digging found several copies of files with that name - though none in a path that should have been touched by the sftp connection. Thanks. Oh, and fyi screen after submitting a support request includes a link to stackoverflow - it says they have support guys listening here too.

Comment: In Jetbrains pycharm, I faced this issue. Went to the root path of remote linux pc and deleted those prompted file, and no more that issue, thanks LazyOne!

Answer (score 2):

I met with the same problem,
but I included logging of errors (description here https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202)
and I saw that I had created a file with incorrect name
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but it was not due to Firefox and I wonder if the original asker might have made the same mistake I did in configuring his xdebug.

As a newbie, in setting the value for `xdebug.remote_log` in my `php.ini` (actually in separate xdebug.ini), I used the windows file path to my project on my local machine. Why? Because the value called "remote_log", so I mistakenly thought it wanted the path on my windows machine, which I thought was very strange at the time. But I am new to remote debugging, so... Oops.

Using windows path is wrong:

```
xdebug.remote_log="C:\Users\Buttle\PhpstormProjects\xdebug_log.txt"
```

And it results in:

/var/www/myproject/**C:\Users\Buttle\PhpstormProjects\xdebug_log.txt**

(the bolded part is the actual file name)

This is right:

xdebug.remote_log="xdebug_log.txt"

And presumably results in:

/var/www/myproject/**xdebug_log.txt**

(the bolded part is the actual file name)

It appears that Xdebug saves that log file inside of the folder where the requested php file came from (in my case, my project's index.php file).

I imagine that if I enter an valid linux path, I might be able to put the file somewhere else. E.g.

This might work:

```
xdebug.remote_log="/var/www/xdebug_log.txt"
```

So this solves 2 problems: 1.) why the heck doesn't xdebug log anything on its server (it does!) 2.) descendant file problem.

Comment: Thanks, but since fixing this I worked out the file was created by Adobe Reader rather than Firefox for me - I suspect several applications may use some lib that generates this file. My Xdebug log was *definitely* using a Linux path!