# PhpStorm invalid descendant file name

Tags: ftp, xampp, phpstorm

This question couldn't  [solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952697/phpstorm-invalid-descendent-file-name).

I got this error `C:\xampp\tmp`, I am using PhpStorm file transfer protocol and I get this error whenever I want to upload any file to my cpanel.

I could only upload files if I delete the folder `c:\xampp\tmp` on my cpanel and after some time the folder will appear again on my cpanel.

The `c:\xamp\tmp` is availabe on my local machine, I presume the file is been uploaded to the server and I don't want it to. the folder I am trying to upload is inside `htdocs`, its a Drupal 7 file.

Comment: If such file "is available on my machine" then either delete it or exclude from uploading (you can mark specific folders/files from being uploaded in Deployment settings). **BTW:** what is your local OS?

Comment: @LazyOne my OS is windows 7, the file is in xamp folder and deleting it might cause some issues in xamp. i tried excluding, but it doesnt work.

Comment: Well ... file with such name simply cannot be transferred on Windows 7 especially using PhpStorm (it will throw exception). 1) Do you have other people accessing that FTP? or maybe you accessing it from another OS/computer? 2) Or maybe that file is created by your code when executed remotely (quite possible)? Check your code then.